# render a template with link_to rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to render a template by clicking on a link .

Here is what I am doing :-

```
link_to "Profile", render :template => "profile"
```

This gives me an error:-

> SyntaxError in Settings#account_setting

Here is my settings controller :-

```
class SettingsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def profile
        @user = current_user
        request.method.inspect
        if request.method == "POST"
          @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
          flash[:notice] = "You updated your profile successfully."
        end
    end

    def account_setting
    end

end
```

This is the error :-

> syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' on this line 
>   %li=link_to"profile", render :template => "profile"

This is the generated markup of the error :-

> syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
>   ...se((link_to("profile", render :template =>
>   "profile"

What could be the issue?

Comment: What kind of partial is it? Show it.

Comment: Do you want to do it without reloading the page?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I just want it there dosent matter if the page is reloading or not

Comment: What does generated markup look like?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am sorry don't know what exactly do you mean by what does the generated markup look like

Comment: @SergioTulentsev updated the question with the generated markup of the error

Comment: Ah, yes, the page can't even be generated. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

```
= link_to 'Profile', @profile
```

This will generate something similar to

```
<a href="/profiles/1">Profile</a>
```

upon clicking which ProfilesController#show will be called and corresponding view rendered.

You can, of course, fire an ajax query here, fetch rendered template and display it dynamically, but I think, it's too early for you now.